# Content View in ScrollView Not Rendering Properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am designing a UIViewController that contains a UIScrollView and that UIScrollView contains a UIView (which I will refer to as content view). The content view has dynamic content so the height of the ScrollView varies. I've created many ViewControllers with this schema, however, this one is a little different in that there can be times where the amount of content that needs to be displayed would result in the view being the same size as the UIView (so the view wouldn't be scrollable because the amount of content can fit on the screen as is).

I am nearly positive that the constraints I set should work for me. I set the left, right, top, bottom constraints on the ScrollView and left, right, top, bottom, and equal width to the 'main' UIView as well as a starting height (which is the same as the ScrollView).

The issue I am seeing is that when the view controller renders, after I deploy, the content view doesn't extend to the same height as the ScrollView (it looks like it gets chopped off). This only happens when the amount of content can fit on the screen as is. When there is too much content to fit on the screen, and the view becomes scrollable, I have no issues (2nd image).

I wasn't sure if the height of the content view was incorrect or if it was the Y position (I have a toolbar so the ScrollView's top constraint is pinned to the bottom of the toolbar -- Y is 64). I then printed the Y positions and heights of the ScrollView and the content view. I got 64 and 0 for the Ys and 603 and 603 for the heights, respectively. the 0 position on the content view makes sense because it's superview is the ScrollView. So given that the Y positions and heights seem to be correct, I have no idea why I am seeing this issue.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgNsF.jpg)

[Screenshot when the view becomes scrollable and the view renders properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7YRU.jpg)

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @PGDev it doesn't hit any code that alters the content view height when the issue occurs -- I am using auto-layout. 

I added a screenshot of the issue. The piece with the red background is the ScrollView and the blue is the content view.